# What is meaning associated with the name Dasharatha?

Tags: ramayana, dasharatha

[Dasharatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasharatha) was a great [Ikshvaku King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ikshvaku_dynasty)(of Ayodhya) and Bhagawan [Shri Ram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Rama)'s father.

**When we take the literal meaning**

Dasharatha or Dasharath  means **ten Chariots**, because sandhi viccheda for Dasharatha would be 
Dasha + Ratha : Dasha means ten and Ratha means chariot.

How can someone have a name like 10 Chariots? is there another meaning or [story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10852/36) associated with this name?

<sup>**Note**: I prefer answer from valid sanskrit dictionary like [Apte](http://www.amazon.in/Practical-Sanskrit-English-Dictionary-V-S-Apte/dp/8120815688) and/or Valmiki Ramayana.</sup>

Comment: I posted a related question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10852/36

Comment: a car can travel front & back. an elevator can travel up & down. but a helicopter can travel front,back,left,right,up,down etc. Dasharatha had a chariot which could travel in 10 directions (ashta dik + up-down). We call people by their qualities or achievements e.g. Arjuna is called Svetavahaha - meaning white vehicle, because his horses were white, or a simple example - if someone always wears a red shirt to work, his friends might just call him 'red-shirt', instead of 'red-shirt-wearer'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the meaning of Dashratha, explained in the [Gloss](https://www.sadagopan.org/index.php/component/djcatalog2/?format=raw&task=download&fid=18) 
(by Swami Sadhagopan) on [Mahaveera Vaibhavam](http://anudinam.org/2012/03/31/raghuveera-gadhyam-%E2%80%93-learners-series-audio/) authored by [Kavitarkika Simha Swami Vedanta Deshikan](http://srivaishnavam.com/desika_life_history.htm) himself.

Quoting from the [Gloss](https://www.sadagopan.org/index.php/component/djcatalog2/?format=raw&task=download&fid=18) on Gadya/Passage 6:

> Hail to thee O Lord, who through your birth liquidated the third debt
>   of your father Dasaratha, who was famous for his help  to Indra in his
>   battles with Asuraas!    Here the reference is to the name of our
>   Lord's father, Dasaratha. **His valor in driving his chariot in all
>   the ten directions to chase the  enemies of Indra  and  to  come  to 
>   the rescue of Indra earned him the name DasaraTa (Dasasu Dikshu
>   Aprathihata Ratha:).**