# Some sources say End of Kaliyuga is near

Tags: vishnu, mahabharata, avatars

(I’m re-posting the question in more suitable form and shall provide an answer with some more facts; please refute if you feel but let this be alive for people to see and comment/answer. I’m just an enthusiast, definitely not a spammer.)

If we match recent/current society with the description gave in [this section of Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm) by the great Muni Markandeya.

The description sounds very familiar – looks like it gives almost identical account of the various characteristics world has demonstrated over the last century or so. Isn’t it?

We can easily verify most of the facts, like collapse of four orders into a common order, the whole world having one kind of food, rulers robbing their subjects by all means, both men and women becoming perfectly free in their behaviour and not tolerating one another's acts, girls themselves choosing their husbands, men ceasing to trust one another, people falsely bearing the marks of religion, men abandoning the countries and directions and towns and cities of their occupation, seeking for new ones, one after another...

It’s not necessary that every fact has to be occurring as is as it might be symbolic to something else, but things like girls of five or six years of age will bring forth children really struck the skeptic in me. However, soon I found that this in fact [became reality in 1930s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_youngest_birth_mothers).

As most of us would know from childhood that we’re in Kaliyug – about 5 thousand years have elapsed – it would take another 432 thousand years for Kaliyug to reach to its end. What if this figure is actually symbolic to something else? What if we’re living during the end period of Kaliyug?

The ask from readers of this question is to provide facts in favor or against of this theory.

Comment: Again, this isn't actually a question.  It's just speculation and a request for others to comment on your speculation.  So I'm closing your question for a second time.  Also, for future reference if your question has been closed you shouldn't delete it and post it again.  You should just edit the question to make it acceptable and then ask that it be reopened.  (You can flag the post so that a moderator will see your reopen request.)

Comment: though it's a speculative one, but speculation is the first step to experimentation and then to verify and believe something IMO.

Comment: Well, things like speculation and experimentation are not the purpose of this site.  The purpose of this site is to ask and answer factual questions concerning Hinduism.  It's not to engage in speculation or to solicit opinion.

Comment: Anyway there's only one agenda behind this question is to put this info out there. and maybe someone would get more info to verify/refute it. I know it invites a kind of discussion but this site is an important online place I found where many intelectual people familiar with and believing in Hindu philosophy and history feequent and who could strive to listen and perhaps take the research forward.

Comment: @keshav also it's not completely speculative some facts have been provided. The ask is to let people provide more facts in favor/against. Earlier on this site similar speculative questions have been asked. See http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/how-did-dasharatha-and-jatayu-become-friends

Comment: @keshav updated question to explicitly ask for facts in favor/against of the theory presented in the question. Can this stand clean now?

Comment: there are actually various sources for this. Some saints say that KaliYuga is going to end soon in the coming few years. Some saints say that it has already ended and we are now in Dvapar Yug. Some say that it is still going on and will continue to go on. Some saints say that each yuga is just an individual transformation in addition to being a world transformation. Its all debatable and no-one really can be sure of the future after all, we are not the all-knowing God (or God-realized) :P

Comment: @sai you are right that we can't say anything precisely. However, as per the scriptures, an avtara does come on Earth at the end of a yuga. We did have divine saints like Ramakrishna paramhansa in 19th century, but a significant impact or change on the world has yet to be seen. The world might have improved technologically, but spiritually it's all diminished further in my view. Add to this, it looks like individual efforts do not seem to make any further improvement; look at growing of tention between Russia and US, the religious fanatics of middle east, growing corruption and mass ... cont

Comment: (cont) surveillance all over the world, failure of democracy in providing justice and accountability, ever-increasing materialistic tendencies – the list may go on. We haven't witnessed an significant eindvidual or set of individuals who, as per the scriptures, would lead in transforming the world into a better state than we've been inheriting. Add to this, we do have Buddha noted as the 9th avatar, but no one has been noted as the 10th avatar yet with such significant impact on world. As per the research paper I sighted, 3000 years difference is a notable take away between yugas and avatars.

Comment: good point. But the thing is, IMHO, these conditions are simply of our own imagination. What we focus on grows. A glass can be looked at as half full or half empty. A positive person will find good things to say about every age. A negative person will find only the negatives of the age. Thus wherever age you are in, it will seem like Kali Yuga if one is negative and every age will seem to be Satya Yuga for the positive person. The important thing is to be happy whatever age it is :)! In my opinion, world is more spiritual now than before! All the best

Comment: @bhakta Even with that small edit, it's still a post that just puts forward a speculative theory and asks others to confirm or refute it.  That's not the sort of thing the site is meant for.

Answer (score 4):

I recently stumbled upon [this research paper](http://www.grahamhancock.com/forum/DMisraB6.php) which I can consider the most important and scientific sort of research regarding yugas that can dispel the myth of Kaliyug having 432 thousand years. As per the paper the four yugas are in fact 3 thousand years each and there are descending and ascending full yuga cycles (each full cycle having 12 thousand Earth years). The paper estimates the end of ascending Kaliyug in 2025. Note: the researcher isn't a working geologist, but rather a technologist. But I found the paper based on good number of facts and therefore I can consider it credible.

Then I also found a [book on Veerabrahmendra](http://veerabrahmendraswami-biography.blogspot.in/2010/03/chapter-2-nandikonda-papaghni-muth.html) – a divine saint born around 1200/1300C, the most interesting thing is the Kalagyana written by him and it has prophecies related to period during the end of Kaliyuga (most of which have already been manifested like world wars ETC). Swami Brahmendra is considered a precursor to lord Kalki and he himself described his time of arrival as Lord Kalki. 
I’m still going through the book. A comment on that page noted:

> According to book, if we calculate, Kaliyug started in 3130BC. BrahmamGaru (Kalki) will born in year 2024-2025AD.. However he will known to World as Kalki in year 2040-2041Ad. He is married at 18 years in year 2042-2043AD. And from 2070AD, Kalki rules the world in his terms.

Similar prediction is made on National discovery channel’s blog from a seemingly different though not disclosed source:

> According to Ajay, the end of the world is not so far from us. The world will end within 2085 AD.

Did the Mayan’s calendar actually refer to the end of Kaliyug (which people has incorrectly interpreted as end of world)? May be, yes. There are lot of convincing evidence from different, independent sources!

Comment: The discovery channel's blogpost is at http://www.nationaldiscoverychannel.com/2013/01/is-kalki-avatar-coming-to-end-world.html . couldn't add due to number of links limitation on new members

Comment: You shouldn't use comments to bypass posting restrictions.  Those restrictions are there for a reason.  If you want to get rid of those restrictions then try earning some reputation. You just need 10 points.

Comment: @keshav The problem is that I wanted to ask this question with putting in whatever sources I've come across as part of the research. However, without points I couldn't add those references and without references my question holds no water/credibility. Now to earn points I had a choice; either ask some completely unrelated question or try to find some unanswered question which I could answer. In both cases, hoping someone would like that and also upvotes. Both don't seem to serve the real purpose that I simply wanted to ask a question

Comment: Please keep adding additional information from the book and if possible also from different sources. Thanks.

Comment: In the book [Prophecies 1998 To 3000](http://www.bookganga.com/eBooks/Books/details/4949669354430424986) by a Yogi, it's stated that world war 3 would take place between 2000-2030 and a yogi will guide india and the world from 2015. It also mentions of coming golden time in this century – a society free of greed and hate.