# Is there any dating available for the book Shri Shani Mahatmya?

Tags: scripture, shani

I wanted to know if anybody has tried dating the book 'Shri Shani Mahatmya'? Is there a version in Hindi/English available online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shani Mahatmya is a Marathi folktale and according to [this website](https://2ndlook.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/folk-worship-in-india-shani-mahatmya/), it's "not from Vedas, puranas, upanishads, or any vedic sanskrit text".  But apart from that, I'm not sure about its dating.

In any case, as far as I know the only English translation of the Shani Mahatmya is Anand Gopte's translation, which you can read [here](http://anand-gupte.tripod.com/shani.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Keshav for researching on this long lost question.

Comment: @Aby You're welcome.  I was interested in this question because "Shani Mahatmya" sounded like a section title of some Purana.  (For instance, the Skanda Purana has sections called the Venkatachala Mahatmya and the Vasudeva Mahatmya, which two of the most interesting sections in the Puranas.). So I was hoping that it would allow me to verify a story about Dasharatha's encounter with Shani, which I asked about here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3044/36 Unfortunately, the Shani Mahatmya has nothing to do with any of that.

Comment: @Aby I found a book from the nineteenth century which lists the author of the Shani Mahaymya as Tatyaji Mahipati: https://books.google.com/books?id=S4hSAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA17-IA85&ots=EnlVp4LGIa&dq=mahipati%20shani&pg=PA17-IA85#v=onepage&q&f=false  That might be the same as this Mahipati: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahipati